# Unable to find pthread Eclipse GCC linker issue

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, gcc, pthreads

I have tried all the other postings on this issue and can confirm I have set up in properties->c/c++ build->Settings->Cross G++ Linker the following:

- -pthread in the linker flags in the Eclipse IDE
- pthread in  properties->c/c++ build->Settings->Cross G++ Linker -> Libraries.

Output fails as follows:

```
16:15:26 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Weatherly ****
make all 
'Building file: ../src/main.cpp'
'Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler'
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/main.d" -MT"src/main.o" -o "src/main.o" "../src/main.cpp"
'Finished building: ../src/main.cpp'
' '
'Building target: Weatherly'
'Invoking: Cross G++ Linker'
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -pthread -Xlinker pthread -o "Weatherly"  ./src/DHT11.o ./src/main.o   -lwiringPi -lpthread
c:/sysgcc/raspberry/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.exe: cannot find pthread: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Weatherly] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

Can someone suggest what might be wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The word `pthread` without a `-` in front of it, is wrong. Can you remove it? It is parsed as a filename which should be added to the linking.

Comment: Given that you are passing the `-pthread` option to `g++` at the link stage, you do not need to also link libpthread explicitly.  And, generally speaking, you *shouldn't* link libpthread explicitly when building with GCC.  Just use the `-pthread` option for  both compiling and linking.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help mch and John. Good pickup on the missing '-' and I have removed the linker reference -lpthread. Compiles just fine now.